# Efficiently convert Numpy 2D array of counts to zero-padded 2D array of indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, indexing

I have a numpy 2D array of n rows (observations) X m columns (features), where each element is the count of times that feature was observed. I need to convert it to a zero-padded 2D array of feature_indices, where each feature_index is repeated a number of times corresponding to the 'count' in the original 2D array.

This seems like it should be a simple combo of `np.where` with `np.repeat` or just expansion using indexing, but I'm not seeing it. Here's a very slow, loopy solution (way too slow to use in practice):

```
# Loopy solution (way too slow!)
def convert_2Dcountsarray_to_zeropaddedindices(countsarray2D):
    rowsums = np.sum(countsarray2D,1)
    max_rowsum = np.max(rowsums)
    out = []
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(countsarray2D):
        out_row = [0]*int(max_rowsum - rowsums[row_idx]) #Padding zeros so all out_rows same length
        for ele_idx in range(len(row)):
            [out_row.append(x) for x in np.repeat(ele_idx, row[ele_idx]) ] 
        out.append(out_row)
    return np.array(out)

# Working example
countsarray2D = np.array( [[1,2,0,1,3],
                           [0,0,0,0,3],
                           [0,1,1,0,0]] )

# Shift all features up by 1 (i.e. add a dummy feature 0 we will use for padding)
countsarray2D = np.hstack( (np.zeros((len(countsarray2D),1)), countsarray2D) )

print(convert_2Dcountsarray_to_zeropaddedindices(countsarray2D))

# Desired result:
array([[1 2 2 4 5 5 5]
       [0 0 0 0 5 5 5]
       [0 0 0 0 0 2 3]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to [`flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) the array and use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html).

This solution requires first adding the number of zeros to use as padding for each row to `countsarray2D`. This can be done as follows:

```py
counts = countsarray2D.sum(axis=1)
max_count = max(counts)
zeros_to_add = max_count - counts
countsarray2D = np.c_[zeros_to_add, countsarray2D]
```

The new `countsarray2D` is then:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
       [5, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Now, we can flatten the array and use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html). An index array `A` is used as the input array while `countsarray2D` determines the number of times each index value should be repeated.

```py
n_rows, n_cols = countsarray2D.shape
A = np.tile(np.arange(n_cols), (n_rows, 1))
np.repeat(A, countsarray2D.flatten()).reshape(n_rows, -1)
```

Final result:

```
array([[1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: Thank you @Shaido. I checked this solution and it's both correct and far faster than the loopy function. This just saved a great deal of runtime.